# Copying of part of the text

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the .txt file with more lines. I need copy text between " " if the ID of the phrase is equal to the necessary

```
"1 one one one one one one ";
"2 twooooooooooooooooooooooooоооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооооoooo;
" 
3 three";
"4 four";
```

I use this method:

```
  string line;
          using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.txt"))
          {
              while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
              {
                  line = reader.ReadLine();
                  if (line.Contains("1")==true)
                      Console.WriteLine(line);
              }
              reader.ReadToEnd();
          }
```

But it not working because sometimes text more than one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
var lines = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt")
     .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
     .Split(new[] { '"', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

In order to get a specific line use `Where` or `FirsOrDefault`:

```
var line = lines.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("1"));
```

Comment: Good, unless the line breaks should be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = File.ReadAllText( @"C:\test.txt" );
var allStrings = text.Split( '"' ).Where( ( s, i ) => i % 2 == 0 );
var specificStrings = allStrings.Where( s => s.StartsWith( "1 " ) );
```

Firstly, my code does not kill the line breaks. Secondly, it reads only what's inside the quotes, totally ignoring what's outside. Then, it clearly defines the steps of processing (file - text - strings - filtered strings). And finally, it correctly searches for string #1, i.e. it won't catch string #11 or #111, etc.

Comment: You should add some text to explain _why_ someone would want to use that code, perhaps by explaining what it does. Pure code answers are only rarely voted up, whereas mixed code and text answers are often voted up (and accepted).

Comment: Firstly, my code does not kill the line breaks. Secondly, it reads only what's inside the quotes, totally ignoring what's outside. Then, it clearly defines the steps of processing (file - text - strings - filtered strings). And finally, it correctly searches for string #1, i.e. it won't catch string #11 or #111, etc.

Comment: Sure, but _edit that into your answer itself_ please. Hit the edit link, put the descriptive text in, and make your answer better. :-)

Comment: Done. That's made one person happy. :-)